# NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER - WMI provider Error

Tags: sql-server

I tried on MS SQL SERVER 2016 Standard change with SQL Configuratin Manager service SQL Agent from **LocalSystem to NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT (without problems)**.

When I change SQL Server service from LocalSystem to NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER i get message "WMI Provider Error" - not object or property found 0x80092004 Systemlog: SQL Server service (MSSQLSERVER) ended with the following specific error Service: object or property is not found. ID: 7024

The server normally works with SQL services under Local System and works without problems. For Database Mail I need to configure the service to NT SERVICE.
SQL run under Windows Server 2012 R2.

I tried unsuccessfully to:
Reboot the server, change login name direct with Services.msc, Powershell get-service | foreach {Write-Host NT Service \ $ ($ _. Name)} NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER exists, WMI Diagnosis Utility (in my opinion, nothing major found).

Thank you for your help ...

Comment: sounds ike a question for [dba.stackexchange.com] or [sf]

Answer (score 0):

I found information than NT SERVICE\ impossible set for SQL accounts
under Domain Controller ... 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/06/25/can-i-install-sql-server-on-a-domain-controller/

Hello, just last two comments ....

1) SQLSERVERAGENT service works without problem

2) I'm surprised that I can not find powershell script for
create permissions and rights SQL folder structure ...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx
I'm alone who have Domain and SQL ... or nobody create separate
user for SQL services ...
- I think the script would be very helpful

Comment: Actually, a well-written question with *all* the information available would be *far* more helpful. You should have mentioned that SQL Server was installed on a DC. That's what causes the problem - DC means "domain controller". Accounts created on that machine have special behavior - modifications to a DC affect the entire domain. I suspect that Setup even gave you a warning about installing on a DC

Comment: Second, the Setup itself offers to create new per-service accounts. It can be done, there are scripts for this. You tried to modify special service accounts on a DC though